# Disclaimer will not show up on first launch of site

Tags: 7, theming

Basically, all I want is a disclaimer/splash page to where it verifies youre 21 (just by clicking yes or no) before accessing the home page. I have the most upgraded versions of jQuery, Colorbox, Libraries, and Disclaimer. Disclaimer settings appear to be fine and should work, however the disclaimer does not show at all and only my home page shows, even in a private cookie free window. Since this did not work, I've tried adding

```
scripts[] =  js/custom.js
```

into the .info file in my theme folder, and creating a folder with a custom.js file with the line

```
( function ($) { $('p').css('color', 'red'); } (jQuery));
```

which did not work either.  Any other modules that are stable and could help me out or any other advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried logging in from a different IP?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no luck